# How to generate a file with DDL in the engine's SQL dialect in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Suppose I have an `engine` pointing at MySQL database:

```
engine = create_engine('mysql://arthurdent:answer42@localhost/dtdb', echo=True)
```

I can populate `dtdb` with tables, FKs, etc by:

```
metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Is there an easy way to generate the SQL file that contains all the DDL statements instead of actually applying these DDL statements to `dtdb`?

So far I have resorted to capturing SQLAlchemy log output produced by `echo=True`, and editing it by hand. But that's just too painful.

It looks like SA has pretty elaborate schema management API, but I haven't seen examples of simply streaming the schema definitions as text.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The quick answer is in the [SQLAlchemy 0.8 FAQ](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/faq.html#how-can-i-get-the-create-table-drop-table-output-as-a-string).

In SQLAlchemy 0.8 you need to do

```
engine = create_engine(
'mssql+pyodbc://./MyDb',
strategy='mock',
executor= lambda sql, *multiparams, **params: print (sql.compile(dialect=engine.dialect)))
```

In SQLAlchemy 0.9 the syntax is simplified.

```
engine = create_engine(
'mssql+pyodbc://./MyDb',
strategy='mock',
executor= lambda sql, *multiparams, **params: print (sql)
```

The longer answer is that capturing the output still has some slight issues. Like with the encoding of literals of types. But this hasn't been a big enough of an issue for anyone to step up and scratch their itch. You could always let SQLAlchemy programmatically create an empty database and dump the SQL from there.

The more difficult problem is the handling of schema migrations. This is where [SQLAlchemy-migrate](https://github.com/openstack/sqlalchemy-migrate) can help you.

Comment: That FAQ link is what I needed, thanks! :)
I wasn't looking for migrations-like schema management. Simply, I needed a simple hack to grab DDL without mucking with engine echo output.

Comment: This seems to have changed in Python 0.9. Also, the FAQ doesn't seem to exist for 0.9.

Comment: The second syntax did not work in SQLAlchemy 1.0.12 for me – see https://groups.google.com/d/topic/sqlalchemy/r9neOsc64wc/discussion